# getting no desired output on printing down the LinkedList in revers form

Tags: java

I wrote down the code to print the list in reverse form and after I found that I am not getting desired output, as per my thinking It should work, but it doesn't. after checking a lot of time I tried to find the problem but still getting no output.

Don't compare the code with the complexity because I know the complexity is not well. This is just an idea to bring up the all possible outcomes.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class printReverse {
    static class Node {
        public int data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    static class SinglyLinkedList {
        public Node head;
        public Node tail;
        
        public SinglyLinkedList() {
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
        }
    }
    
        // Insert the node to the LinkedList method 
        static void add (Node head, int data) {
            Node node = new Node(data);
            Node current = head;
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
            }
            else {
                current.next = node;
            }
            current = node;
        }

        // ArrayList insertion 
        static void insert (Node head, ArrayList<Integer> a) {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null) {
                a.add(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }         

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int t = scan.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();
                int n = scan.nextInt();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    int value = scan.nextInt();
                    add(list.head, value);
                }

                ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
                insert(list.head, array);    

                // Printing ArrayList revsrse
                System.out.println(array);                                   
            }
            scan.close();            
        }        
}
```

The problem is not adding the node value to the linked list to the (add) method.

Answer (score 0):

code needed a few changes.

```
class Node {
public int data;
public Node next;

public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
}
```

}

```
class SinglyLinkedList {
    public Node head;
    public Node tail;
public SinglyLinkedList() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
}

// Insert the node to the LinkedList method
public void add (Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        head.next = node;
        head = node;
    }
    if (tail == null) {
        tail = node;
    }
}
public void print (Node node) {
    if (node.next != null) {
        print(node.next);
    }
    System.out.println(node.data);
}
```

}

in the main method you can call add method alone if you want to add any node to the list.

SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();

this code should be out side of the loops because you want a single linked list, if you want to have multiple single linked lists then you can have them inside a loop.

to print the `list` elements you can traverse all the nodes from tail and print the `data` with in it. you cannot traverse back from head as head doesn't contain previous node reference.